# JavaScript function to replace URL param not working as intended

Tags: javascript

I have a function to replace my URL parameters on pagination buttons. If my `URL` is `https://example.com/`, I get correct `URL` in result, but if my `URL` already has some parameters, like in the **fiddle**, only the last parameter is replaced. How can I get correct `URL` in this case also?

```js
var sURL = "https://example.com/?&page=2&order=price&direction=ASC";
//var sURL = "https://example.com/"; 
function insertParam(no, ord, dir) {
  var page = "page";
  var order = "order";
  var direction = "direction";
  page = encodeURI(page);
  order = encodeURI(order);
  direction = encodeURI(direction);

  no = encodeURI(no);
  ord = encodeURI(ord);
  dir = encodeURI(dir);

  var kvp = sURL.substr(1).split('&');

  var i = kvp.length;
  var x;

  while (i--) {
    x = kvp[i].split('=');

    if (x[0] === page) {
      x[1] = no;
      kvp[i] = x.join('=');
      break;
    }
    if (x[0] === order) {
      x[1] = ord;
      kvp[i] = x.join('=');
      break;
    }
    if (x[0] === direction) {
      x[1] = dir;
      kvp[i] = x.join('=');
      break;
    }
  }

  if (i < 0) {
    kvp[kvp.length] = [page, no].join('=');
    kvp[kvp.length] = [order, ord].join('=');
    kvp[kvp.length] = [direction, dir].join('=');
  }
 sURL = kvp.join('&');
  alert(sURL);
}

insertParam(3, 'my_id', 'DESC');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/URL) class. It helps you to deal with all the weird URL-related stuff. Here's your function using it:

```js
var sURL = "https://example.com/?&page=2&order=price&direction=ASC";

function insertParam(page = 2, order = "price", direction = "ASC") {
  const u = new URL(sURL);
  u.searchParams.set("page", page);
  u.searchParams.set("order", order);
  u.searchParams.set("direction", direction);
  return u.toString();
}

console.log(insertParam(1, "foo", "DESC"));

console.log(insertParam(5));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

or a more generic solution

```js
const urlBuilder = (url, defaults = {}) => (props) => {
  const u = new URL(url);
  for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(props ? { ...defaults, ...props } : defaults)) {
    u.searchParams.set(key, value);
  }
  return u.toString();
}

// create a function that will build the urls for a particular page/route
const routeFoo = urlBuilder("https://example.com", {
  page: 2,
  order: "price",
  direction: "ASC"
});

console.log(routeFoo({
  page: 5
}));

console.log(routeFoo({
  page: 1,
  direction: "DESC",
  foo: 42,
  additional: "properties",
  "also deals with weird/malicious stuff": "like special chars like /#%? & more"
}));

// or just the defaults
console.log(routeFoo());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

Comment: using your first `function` and modifying a bit worked for me, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to follow another approach to achieve your requirement, Hope it will help you.

```
function insertParam(endpoint, no, ord, dir){
const sURL = endpoint + "?&page=" + no + "&order=" + ord + "&direction=" + dir;
return sURL
}

const url = insertParam("https://example.com/", 2, 123, "ASC");
// https://example.com/?&page=2&order=123&direction=ASC
```

Comment: never ever forget to `encodeUriComponent()` the passed arguments, or eventually you'll have something like this: `insertParam("https://example.com/", 2, "&bar=13")` in your code

Comment: @Thomas I will definitely do that! :)

Comment: @HaseebHassy just to be clear: that's the job of the code INSIDE the function to ensure that it properly encodes the passed values, not the job of the code that passes values to this function

Answer (score 0):

Try Using 
newurl= location.search.replace(/^.*?\=/, '');
newurl=newurl.replace("+","");